# DPDK compiler error on fedora 23

Tags: dpdk

Attempting to build DPDK 16.04 and am getting an error.  I've done a little hunting around and some of the solutions are "update the kernel"  I am currently running Fedora 23.  There is a uname -a below with the exact version.   I think what I am really looking for is more information about what is wrong.  The error message seems vague.  My next step is to dig into the make file and see what was going on just prior to the error.  Any suggestions on getting more information about the error would be appreciated.

```
[rmaes@ruwv-pbullock-2 dpdk-16.04]$ make config T=x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc
Configuration done
[rmaes@ruwv-pbullock-2 dpdk-16.04]$ make
== Build lib
== Build lib/librte_compat
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_compat.h
== Build lib/librte_eal
== Build lib/librte_eal/common
  SYMLINK-FILE include/generic/rte_atomic.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/generic/rte_byteorder.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/generic/rte_cycles.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/generic/rte_prefetch.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/generic/rte_spinlock.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/generic/rte_memcpy.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/generic/rte_cpuflags.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/generic/rte_rwlock.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_branch_prediction.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_common.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_debug.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_eal.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_errno.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_launch.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_lcore.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_log.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_memory.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_memzone.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_pci.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_pci_dev_ids.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_per_lcore.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_random.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_tailq.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_interrupts.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_alarm.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_string_fns.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_version.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_eal_memconfig.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_malloc_heap.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_hexdump.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_devargs.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_dev.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_pci_dev_feature_defs.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_pci_dev_features.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_malloc.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_keepalive.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_time.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_rwlock.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_memcpy.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_cycles.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_spinlock.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_atomic_32.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_vect.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_prefetch.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_byteorder_32.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_atomic_64.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_rtm.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_cpuflags.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_byteorder_64.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_atomic.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_byteorder.h
== Build lib/librte_eal/linuxapp
== Build lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal
  CC eal.o
  CC eal_hugepage_info.o
  CC eal_memory.o
  CC eal_thread.o
  CC eal_log.o
  CC eal_pci.o
  CC eal_pci_uio.o
  CC eal_pci_vfio.o
  CC eal_pci_vfio_mp_sync.o
  CC eal_debug.o
  CC eal_lcore.o
  CC eal_timer.o
  CC eal_interrupts.o
  CC eal_alarm.o
  CC eal_common_lcore.o
  CC eal_common_timer.o
  CC eal_common_memzone.o
  CC eal_common_log.o
  CC eal_common_launch.o
  CC eal_common_pci.o
  CC eal_common_pci_uio.o
  CC eal_common_memory.o
  CC eal_common_tailqs.o
  CC eal_common_errno.o
  CC eal_common_cpuflags.o
  CC eal_common_string_fns.o
  CC eal_common_hexdump.o
  CC eal_common_devargs.o
  CC eal_common_dev.o
  CC eal_common_options.o
  CC eal_common_thread.o
  CC eal_common_proc.o
  CC rte_malloc.o
  CC malloc_elem.o
  CC malloc_heap.o
  CC rte_keepalive.o
  CC rte_cpuflags.o
  AR librte_eal.a
  SYMLINK-FILE include/exec-env/rte_interrupts.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/exec-env/rte_kni_common.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/exec-env/rte_dom0_common.h
  INSTALL-LIB librte_eal.a
== Build lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/igb_uio
make[6]: *** /lib/modules/4.2.3-300.fc23.x86_64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
/home/rmaes/Downloads/dpdk-16.04/mk/rte.module.mk:79: recipe for target 'igb_uio.ko' failed
make[5]: *** [igb_uio.ko] Error 2
/home/rmaes/Downloads/dpdk-16.04/mk/rte.subdir.mk:61: recipe for target 'igb_uio' failed
make[4]: *** [igb_uio] Error 2
/home/rmaes/Downloads/dpdk-16.04/mk/rte.subdir.mk:61: recipe for target 'linuxapp' failed
make[3]: *** [linuxapp] Error 2
/home/rmaes/Downloads/dpdk-16.04/mk/rte.subdir.mk:61: recipe for target 'librte_eal' failed
make[2]: *** [librte_eal] Error 2
/home/rmaes/Downloads/dpdk-16.04/mk/rte.sdkbuild.mk:77: recipe for target 'lib' failed
make[1]: *** [lib] Error 2
/home/rmaes/Downloads/dpdk-16.04/mk/rte.sdkroot.mk:123: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
[rmaes@ruwv-pbullock-2 dpdk-16.04]$ uname -a
Linux ruwv-pbullock-2 4.2.3-300.fc23.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Oct 5 15:42:54 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[rmaes@ruwv-pbullock-2 dpdk-16.04]$
```

Comment: Ok, found a little more information. /lib/modules/4.2.3-300.fc23.x86_64/build exists, but it is a softlink
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root      38 Oct  5  2015 build -> /usr/src/kernels/4.2.3-300.fc23.x86_64
/usr/src/kernels/4.2.3-300.fc23.x86_64 doesn't exist.  I'll get that fixed and update.

Comment: So did a sudo yum install kernel-devel-4.2.3-300.fc23.x86_64 and all is well.  Compiles without error.

Comment: Had a similar issue and doing dnf install kernel-devel-4.2.3-300.fc23.x86_64 fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did a sudo yum install kernel-devel-4.2.3-300.fc23.x86_64 and all is well. Compiles without error.